# creating ingame menu in Android using addContentView

Tags: android

I am trying to make a game for android. It is based on a 2d map, which the user can move around the screen. On the screen are several buttons, for example 'Shop'. When I user presses the button, I would like to fill the screen with a shop interface.

So far my approach has been as follows:

I have a mapView, and a map thread

- `public class MapView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {}`
- `public class MapThread extends Thread { ... }`

The map thread periodically calls the `onDraw` method in MapView, which draws the map to the screen, whilst event listeners in `MapView` deal with moving the map.

For the shop, I have a similar setup, with a `ShopThread` and a `ShopView`. When the shop button is pressed, my idea is to stop the `MapThread`, and start the `ShopThread`. This would mean only the 'onDraw' method of `ShopView` will be called, allowing me to draw the shop interface.

In reponse to the button press I have the following code:
(I pass the activity between each of the views via the variable `topPage`)

```
    mapThread.isRunning = false; //stop the map thread
    setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    // add showView to the activity and start the ShopThread
    topPage.addContentView(shopView,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT) );
        shopView.startThread();
```

My problem is that the game freezes for a while when trying to access the shop. The screen just remains black and doesn't respond for around 30 seconds to a minute. I will also get the 'force close' or 'wait' error message from the OS. If I press wait, the ShopView will occasionally start working completely correctly.

I have narrowed it down to the run method in my `ShopThread` class.

```
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (isRunning){
        c = null;
        try {
            c = ShopView.getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (ShopView.getHolder()) {
                if(c != null)
                ShopView.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if( c != null){
                ShopView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `c = ShopView.getHolder().lockCanvas(null);` is simply returning null. I have placed Log.v statements in the other updateThreads and they appear to have all stopped. What is keeping a lock on the canvas, is there something I am missing?

Comment: I found the problem. I managed to fix it, but I am unsure why is was a problem in the first place.

I originally created a `ShopView` object in my `MapView` class and started the `ShopThread` manually when I wanted to start drawing the shop to the canvas. Instead of this, I changed it so that the ShopView thread was created when needed by using in the `surfaceCreated()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I managed to fix it, but I am unsure why is was a problem in the first place.

I originally created a `ShopView` object in my `MapView` class and started the `ShopThread` manually when I wanted to start drawing the shop to the canvas. Instead of this, I changed it so that the ShopView thread was created and started in the `surfaceCreated()` function